# Bootstrap 4 (Angular) navbar collapse button not working

Tags: css, angular, twitter-bootstrap

I am using this code example to implement a collapsible navbar using Bootstrap 4 in an Angular project.

Bootstrap was installed using `npm` along with Popper and jQuery. Versions:

```
angular/core: 8.2.5

angular/cli: 8.3.3

bootstrap: 4.3.1

popper: 1.0.1

popper.js: 1.15.0

jquery: 3.4.1
```

As shown below in the screenshot, decreasing the window size collapses the navbar and shows the hamburger button. However the hamburger button does nothing No errors are logged in the console.

[image]

Here is my code for the navigation:

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-md navbar-light bg-light">
  <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">chumiest bucket</a>
  <button class="navbar-toggler" 
    type="button" 
    data-toggle="collapse" 
    data-target="#collapsingNavbar" 
    aria-expanded="false" 
    aria-label="Toggle navigation"
    >
      <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
  </button>
  <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="collapsingNavbar">
      <ul class="navbar-nav ml-auto">
          <li class="nav-item">
              <a class="nav-link" href="#">Link</a>
          </li>
          <li class="nav-item">
              <a class="nav-link" href="#">Link</a>
          </li>
          <li class="nav-item">
              <a class="nav-link" href="#">Link</a>
          </li>
      </ul>
  </div>
</nav>
```

The answers I've come across all stem from not having the proper CDN link (which I'm not using); the method I'm going with may not be correct.

Answer (score 0):

### What Worked

add Popper, Bootstrap and jQuery JavaScript files to `angular.json` "scripts" list like this:

```
...
"scripts": [
  "./node_modules/jquery/dist/jquery.js",
  "./node_modules/popper.js/dist/umd/popper.js",
  "./node_modules/bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.js"
]
```